# Smooth vector field vanishing at exactly 6 points

Tags: differential-geometry, geometric-topology

Let $ E $ be the ellipsoid in $ \mathbb{R}^3 $ given by, $$ E = \left \{ (x,y,z) \mid \frac{x^2}{9} + \frac{y^2}{4} + z^2 = 1 \right \} $$ Find a smooth vector field $ H : \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3 $, such that $ H(v) $ is tangent to $ E $ for each $ v \in E $ and $ H $ vanishes at exactly $ 6 $ points of $ E $.

My idea : It suffices to find such vector field $ H $ for $ S^2 $, the unit sphere since there is an orthogonal transformation mapping $ E $ to $ S^2 $. Taking three mutually orthogonal planes through the origin would give us $ 6 $ good points on the sphere, for simplicity, take the coordinate planes $ x=0, y=0, z=0 $. Now, if $ n,s $ are the north and south poles, then planes passing through $ n,s $ and perpendicular to $ z=0 $ cut $ S^2 $ in great circles. For each such circle $ C $, consider $ C \backslash \{n,s\} $ and define $ F $, the field of unit vectors tangent to $ C $ on $ C \backslash \{n,s\} $. Thus $ F $ is defined on $ S^2 \backslash \{n,s\} $. Let $ H $ be the vector field obtained by multiplying the function $ (1-x^2)(1-y^2)(1-z^2) $ with $ F $ on $ S^2 \backslash \{n,s\} $ and $ 0 $ on $ n,s $. Does this work?

Comment: "...since there is an orthogonal transformation mapping $ E $ to $ S^2 $" No, there isn't.

Comment: $ x \rightarrow (\frac{bc}{a^2})^{\frac{1}{3}} x $.., etc, maps an ellipsoid to a sphere. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your transformation is not orthogonal.

Comment: The matrix of the transformation has orthogonal rows does not imply that the transformation is orthogonal. I confused myself. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are working too hard. The fact that the principal axes have different lengths is supposed to *help* you.

**Hint**: On the sphere, the unit normal vector field is always parallel to the vector field $x\partial_x + y\partial_y + z\partial_z$. But for a general surface this is not true.

- Why?
- At how many points are the two vector fields parallel for your surface?
- Can you use this to construct a good vector field?

Comment: If you know some Morse theory: instead of a "rectilinear height function", the above hint suggests a different way of measuring "height".

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, I do not understand your notation $ x \partial_x + y \partial_y + z \partial_z $. I am taking a course on multivariable calculus, I do not know Morse theory.

Comment: @the_hermit: This isn't Morse theory. The $\partial_x$ is notation that means "the component in the $x$-direction", so that Willie's vector field, in notation you might be more comfortable with, might be called $\langle x,y,z\rangle$ or maybe $x\bf{i}$$ + y\bf{j}$$ + z \bf k$.

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks! Obviously, the unit normal vector field for a sphere is parallel to $ (x,y,z) $ since it is radial, but this doesn't hold true for surfaces in general. For $ E $, we have the normal vector at a point $ p=(x,y,z) $ is $ (\frac{x}{9}, \frac{y}{4}, z) $, so the only points at which the two vector fields are parallel are the endpoints of the axes. Trying to figure out how to use this in step 3.

Comment: Well, for point $ v $ on the ellipsoid, if the normal vector is $ n_v $, then take $ H(v) = v - \frac{ \langle v, n_v \rangle}{|n_v|^2} n_v $. Then, $ H $ is a smooth map, $ H(v) $ is tangent at $ v $, and vanishes only at the above $ 6 $ points. I hope this is correct..

Comment: @the_hermit exactly right.